# How to troubleshoot KeyNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, javascriptserializer

I am using the following to deserialize a JSON string into my own class:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<string, object> x = (Dictionary<string, object>)serializer.DeserializeObject(json);
MyJsonStruct data = serializer.Deserialize<MyJsonStruct>(x["d"].ToString());
```

But as soon as the `JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize()` method is called, an exception is thrown:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
```

Is there a way to find out **which key** triggered the exception?

A general technique (or recipe) for troubleshooting this type of exception would be most appreciated.

**Update:** If I remove the `[d]`, I receive the following:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Web.Extensions.dll
System.ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)
```

But again, I am looking for a general technique more than just solving this particular instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop a break point on the Deserialize statement, then use the Immediate Window to type in `x["d"].ToString()`.  This will tell you what that evaluates to, which will equate to the key you are attempting to deserialize.

If you get an error while evaluating that, then your x dictionary does not have "d" as a key, which is another thing you can check.

EDIT: I don't think Daniel was suggesting you remove the `["d"]` completely. If you do that, you are passing Deserialize a dictionary when it's pretty clearly expecting a string.  This type mismatch is what causes the new error you see.  Instead, Daniel is suggesting that the dictionary you have doesn't include `"d"` as a valid key.  Which it may or may not, I'm not sure.

Comment: Great tip, thanks! I'll go ahead and try it. In the meanwhile, see my update in the OP.

Comment: Thanks. When I place the breakpoint and do what you advised, I get the value `'x["d"]' threw an exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException'` for that *x["d"].ToString()*. So, it looks like it is the source of the problem, but how do I handle a dictionary that doesn't have a `d` as the first (and only) key?

Comment: @NotSoSharp Dictionaries do not need to have `"d"` as a key.  I would recommend you put the `x` variable under watch in Visual Studio so you can expand it and look at it as much as you want.  In particular you might check the `.Count` attribute.  If it's 0, you don't have any keys at all.

Comment: Success! Turns out the `.ToString()` was completely misleading (that's what happens when I try to learn from [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2077533/1731850)). Also turns out that the `Dictionary<string, object> x = (Dictionary<string, object>)serializer.DeserializeObject(json);` statement was completely unnecessary: All I had to do is pass the raw `json` string to `Deserialize()`. I should've known better. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

Likely its on your `x` accessing the value for `d`.

Comment: By using the `d` I'm merely following the tip how [.NET 3.5+ adds 'D' to the result](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2077533/1731850). If I remove it, I get an even more scary barrage of `Invalid JSON primitive` exception.