# How do I create treeView from JSON data

Tags: c#, json, winforms, json.net, treeview

I have a JSON file content like this:

```
{
    "cars": [
        {
            "code": "MB-GLS",
            "name": "Mercedes-Benz GLS 350 d 4MATIC",
            "stock": {
                "AMG 9G-Tronic 2016 Blue",
                "4M AMG 2017 Black"
            }
        },
        {
            "code": "BM-420D",
            "name": "BMW 420d Cabrio",
            "stock": {
                "420d Cabrio Luxury Line 2015 White",
                "M Sport 420d Cabrio Red 2018",
                "420d Cabrio Premium 2014 Black",
                "420d Cabrio Premium 2015 White"
            }
        },
        {
            "code": "AU-A5",
            "name": "A5 Sportback 2.0 TDI quattro",
            "stock": {
                "2.0 TDI quattro Dynamic 2018 Grey",
                "2.0 TDI quattro S-Line 2018 Black",
                "2.0 TDI quattro S-Line 2018 Indigo",
                "2.0 TDI quattro Design 2017 White",
                "2.0 TDI quattro Design 2016 Black"
            }
        },
        {
            "code": "TS-MOS",
            "name": "Tesla Model S",
            "stock": {
                "Model S 75D 525 PS 2018 White",
                "Model S 75D 525 PS 2018 Indigo",
                "Model S 90D 2017 Red",
                "Model S P100D 775 PS 2018 Smoke-Colored",
                "Model S P100D 775 PS 2018 White",
                "Model S P85+ 2013 Blue"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to create a treeview content from this JSON data on the WinForms. And I want to use `treeView1` control for it too. Lastly I am using JSON.Net for create JSON object.

The result I hope is the following: [TreeView content with created photoshop for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcqm0.jpg)

I don't any idea, how can I manage this.

**EDIT :** When I try [Creating tree view dynamically according to json text in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769634/creating-tree-view-dynamically-according-to-json-text-in-winforms) subjected example, it gives an error like this: `Invalid character after parsing property name. Exprected ':' but got: ,. Path 'cars[0].stock', line 7, position 29.`. It gives, because it wants stock like this:

```
   "stock": {
        "1": "420d Cabrio Luxury Line 2015 White",
        "2": "M Sport 420d Cabrio Red 2018",
        "3": "420d Cabrio Premium 2014 Black",
        "4": "420d Cabrio Premium 2015 White"
    }
```

But our stock does not like this.

And finally when I try [How to recursively populate a TreeView with JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673815/how-to-recursively-populate-a-treeview-with-json-data)
 it gives an error like this: `Illegal characters in path', line 7, position 29.`. I checked json data, you also see, there is no error in the JSON data.

Comment: You might want to add a tag so we know which UI API you're using.

Comment: Is it a desktop or web application where in you would need a tree view

Comment: @john, I don't know, do I have to use JSON.Net. Think like that: `string json = "{\n\"cars\":[\";...`

Comment: Take a look at [How to recursively populate a TreeView with JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39673815/3744182).  Does that answer your question?

Comment: I felt I needed to open up a new topic because I could not find the answer to the other question.

Comment: @JackEagle - your JSON is not well-formed.  Upload it to https://jsonlint.com/ and you will get an error, `Error: Parse error on line 6: Expecting ':', got ','`.  The problem is that you have a property `"stock": { "string", "string" }`.  That looks like an array of strings, but as explained at http://www.json.org/ an array must be surrounded by brackets `[` and `]`, not braces.  So you will need to fix your JSON to be well-formed in order to parse it with any JSON parser.

Comment: @dbc - Ok! Thank you very much. I will try as you say.